# Sorting algorithm gone wrong

Tags: php

im trying to translate a sortingmethod from Javascript to php and i have run in to some trouble.

The code looks as follows:

```
private static function quicksort($ids, $dists, $left, $right) {
    if ($right - $left <= 20) {
        for ($i = $left + 1; $i <= $right; $i++) {
            $temp = $ids[$i];
            $tempDist = $dists[$temp];
            $j = $i - 1;
            while ($j >= $left && $dists[$ids[$j]] > $tempDist) {
                $ids[$j + 1] = $ids[$j--];
            }
            $ids[$j + 1] = $temp;
        }
    } else {
        $median = ($left + $right) >> 1;
        $i = $left + 1;
        $j = $right;
        self::swap($ids, $median, $i);
        if ($dists[$ids[$left]] > $dists[$ids[$right]]) self::swap($ids, $left, $right);
        if ($dists[$ids[$i]] > $dists[$ids[$right]]) self::swap($ids, $i, $right);
        if ($dists[$ids[$left]] > $dists[$ids[$i]]) self::swap($ids, $left, $i);

        $temp = $ids[$i];
        $tempDist = $dists[$temp];
        while (true) {

                do $i++; while ($dists[$ids[$i]] < $tempDist);
                do $j--; while ($dists[$ids[$j]] > $tempDist);

            if ($j < $i) break;
            self::swap($ids, $i, $j);
        }
        $ids[$left + 1] = $ids[$j];
        $ids[$j] = $temp;

        if ($right - $i + 1 >= $j - $left) {
            self::quicksort($ids, $dists, $i, $right);
            self::quicksort($ids, $dists, $left, $j - 1);
        } else {
            self::quicksort($ids, $dists, $left, $j - 1);
            self::quicksort($ids, $dists, $i, $right);
        }
    }
}



private static function swap($arr, $i, $j) {
    $tmp = $arr[$i];
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$j];
    $arr[$j] = $tmp;
}
```

I run this code with these parameters:

- $ids    - array with 80 objects
- $dists  - array with 80 objects
- $left   - 0
- $right  - 79

and get an error on this line saying Undefined offset: 161

```
                    do $i++; while ($dists[$ids[$i]] < $tempDist);
```

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise? If not, you should just use [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: _I'm trying to translate a sortingmethod from Javascript to php..._ Why?

Comment: JavaScript allows accessing of non-existent array elements or string positions, and will just return `undefined` without issuing any warning or error; PHP however does not, and gives you an “undefined index/offset” in such a case. So you need to test whether what you want to access exists first.

Comment: @KarstenKoop: No but it is a part of a larger library that i am translating so i want it to be the same method.

Comment: @B001ᛦ: because i need the code to run serverside and i dont have node.js

Comment: @misorude: thanks =)